# Can not use add-apt-repository due to SSL connection timeout

Tags: 11.10, add-apt-repository

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 i386. Please help me. I cannot use `add-apt-repository`:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/vlc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 88, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (28, 'SSL connection timeout at 298976')
```

Comment: Look here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/204415

Answer (score 3):

As [Call me V commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107649/can-not-use-add-apt-repository-due-to-ssl-connection-timeout#comment345928_107649), the solution (devised by [actionparsnip](https://launchpad.net/~andrew-woodhead666)) to a very similar problem was to run:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-properties-common
```

Source: [Launchpad Question 204415](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/204415)

I recommend that, *before* running that, you run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

(But go ahead and run the `--reinstall install` command even if you get errors in the `update` command.)

There were other solutions discussed earlier in [that Launchpad question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/204415), so if the above way doesn't work, I recommend checking that, *especially if you have  (or have ever had) a proxy server configured for web access.*

Ultimately, this is a crash--`add-apt-repository` should not behave like this, even if something goes wrong when it tries to add the repository. Therefore, *if you can still produce this problem*, I recommend [reporting it as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). You can configure Apport to send the important technical information to Launchpad; see [How do I submit a full bug report with crash dump and steps to reproduce?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150476/how-do-i-submit-a-full-bug-report-with-crash-dump-and-steps-to-reproduce)