# fixing locale settings permanently

Tags: language-support, locale

I am getting the 'unsupported locale setting' error as referenced [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205378/unsupported-locale-setting-fault-by-command-not-found/264434#264434) (on Ubuntu 13.10).
However, following Martijn [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/264434/249122) only fixes the problem temporarily. Opening a new bash reverts to the 'unsupported locale' problem. 
Any ideas how I can fix this permanently?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an Ubuntu desktop, use **System Settings -> Language Support**.

Otherwise you may want to study a [general guide on setting environment variables persistently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables) in Ubuntu.

Comment: I've narrowed the required settings to only the "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8". However, I've read the general guide, and still not sure where I should put it. 
I have it in the .bashrc file, and it works. But I feel it's a work-around.

Comment: Assuming it's a server you have, add to `/etc/default/locale` the line `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` (without the `export`). Setting `LC_ALL` persistently like that is usually not a good idea.