# (gimp:3877): Pango-WARNING **:

Tags: gimp

Gimp keeps crashing when I try to use the fonts from text tool.

[image: (gimp:3877): Pango-WARNING **:]

```
(gimp:3877): Pango-WARNING **: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly    output.  the offending font is 'rsfs10 Italic 16'

(gimp:3877): Pango-WARNING **: font_face status is: <unknown error status>

(gimp:3877): Pango-WARNING **: scaled_font status is: out of memory

(script-fu:3883): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: This looks similar, http://forums.freebsd.org/archive/index.php/t-19099.html not sure if it will help any.

Comment: Did you check out: http://useranswer.com/answer/gimp3877-pango-warning/

Comment: Questions reporting bugs are considered off-topic for our site (see [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)). This should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). You can [make Apport collect and submit the necessary technical information](http://askubuntu.com/a/244982/22949)--but still make sure to read the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first, and describe the problem thoroughly in the bug report you write in the web browser (which will come up automatically after Apport sends the data).

Answer (score 3):

gimp-2.8.4 was crashing in a very similar way for me, specifically when I attempted to use the text tool.  I resolved my issue by changing the permissions on all of my font files, using something similar to the following.

```
sudo find /usr/share/fonts -type f -name "*.[o,t]tf" -exec chmod 775 '{}' \;
```

Note:  Be sure to run the command for all directories listed in Edit->Preferences->Folders->Fonts.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your ~/.fonts directory. Check rsfs10 font is installed or not. If installed check whether it is properly installed. Its better to delete the font and reinstall.

To install rsfs10 font, Open terminal and type the command

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-lyx
```

More information about the package.

- http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.10/getdeb-apps-i386/ttf-lyx_2.0.4-1~getdeb2_all.deb.html
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/quantal/lyx
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/ttf-lyx

Comment: ttf-lyx wasn't installed so I installed it but Gimp still crashes with the same error message.