# Geary Mail keeps crashing in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: email, geary

Every time I open geary it stays open for a few seconds and then crashes. How can I fix this?

Comment: Programs should never *crash* - so it sounds like a bug to me. Does it sound like [bug #1064314](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/geary/+bug/1064314)? What have you tried? What version are you using? (from repositories?)

Comment: What kind of server are you connecting to?  You might try running Geary like this to see its log: $ geary --debug

Comment: Questions reporting bugs (like crashes) are considered off-topic for our site (see [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)). This should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). You can [make Apport collect and submit the necessary technical information](http://askubuntu.com/a/244982/22949)--but still make sure to read the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first, and describe the problem thoroughly in the bug report you write in the web browser (which will come up automatically after Apport sends the data).