# GPU lockup on Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E130

Tags: 12.10, intel-graphics, intel, lenovo, thinkpad

I recently bought a netbook Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E130 (Video card Intel HD Graphics, CPU Intel Pentium B997 ULV) on which I installed Ubuntu 12.10 64 bits.

A systematic bug makes it annoying to use the laptop.

Regulary, a pop-up shows up, says that the system is bugging. Then, another one, which says:

> Apport has detected a possible GPU hang.  Did your system recently lock up and/or require a hard reboot?"

If I read the bug report, it says:

```
 [sandybridge-m-gt1] GPU lockup IPEHR: 0x41100000 IPEHR:0x0b140001
```

[image]
 If I understand, it affects `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, but I don't understand what is the problem.

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5612225/) is the output from my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide us with a link to the bug report?

Comment: Thanks. I've added the links that you provided to your question. Feel free to delete these comments.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: This should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). You can [make Apport collect and submit the necessary technical information](http://askubuntu.com/a/244982/22949)--but still make sure to read the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first, and describe the problem thoroughly in the bug report you write in the web browser (which will come up automatically after Apport sends the data).

Comment: [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1160294) is corrected in Ubuntu 13.04.