# ubuntu 13.04 python3.3/tkinter/ibus/X11 crash bug where to next

Tags: xorg, ibus, python3

I want to report a crash bug in python3.3.2 that seems to be happening in X11 but am not sure where to go next.  The bug happens when I reset ibus for Japanese input.  I've compiled Python3.3.2 and tk8.6 with debug.  The stack trace is below.  The crash is in X11 -- which is beyond my knowledge.  Where do I report this?

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5.91.20130417-cvs-ubuntu
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python3.3...done.

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 20441]
[New LWP 20442]

warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/bin/python3 ./WorldUnitsConvert.py'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00000153 in ?? ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000153 in ?? ()
#1  0xb6cb9b91 in Xutf8LookupString () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
#2  0xb70893bf in TkpGetString (winPtr=0xa4838f8, eventPtr=0xbfbcdac8, 
    dsPtr=0xbfbcdb28)
    at /home/sjs/dev/python/tk8.6.0/unix/../unix/tkUnixKey.c:122
#3  0xb70833ed in TransferXEventsToTcl (display=0xa239e10)
    at /home/sjs/dev/python/tk8.6.0/unix/../unix/tkUnixEvent.c:342
#4  0xb708348a in DisplayCheckProc (clientData=0x0, flags=-3)
    at /home/sjs/dev/python/tk8.6.0/unix/../unix/tkUnixEvent.c:382
#5  0xb6eb8676 in Tcl_DoOneEvent (flags=-3)
    at /home/sjs/dev/python/tcl8.6.0/generic/tclNotify.c:963
#6  0xb715fe5c in Tkapp_MainLoop (selfptr=0xb71dd7a8, args=0xb70ed45c)
    at /home/sjs/dev/python/Python-3.3.2/Modules/_tkinter.c:2542
#7  0x0821763c in PyCFunction_Call (func=0xb641276c, arg=0xb70ed45c, kw=0x0)
    at Objects/methodobject.c:81
#8  0x08106adb in call_function (pp_stack=0xbfbcddc4, oparg=1)
    at Python/ceval.c:4063
#9  0x08100dff in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=0xb71aa484, throwflag=0)
    at Python/ceval.c:2679
#10 0x08104b51 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (_co=0xb717abf0, globals=0xb72bdb5c, 
    locals=0x0, args=0xb758da0c, argcount=1, kws=0xb758da10, kwcount=0, 
    defs=0xb71b0358, defcount=1, kwdefs=0x0, closure=0x0)
    at Python/ceval.c:3433
#11 0x08107041 in fast_function (func=0xb71b3bd4, pp_stack=0xbfbce614, n=1, 
    na=1, nk=0) at Python/ceval.c:4161
#12 0x08106c71 in call_function (pp_stack=0xbfbce614, oparg=0)
    at Python/ceval.c:4084
#13 0x08100dff in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=0xb758d8cc, throwflag=0)
    at Python/ceval.c:2679
#14 0x08104b51 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (_co=0xb7207b88, globals=0xb72e67a4, 
    locals=0xb72e67a4, args=0x0, argcount=0, kws=0x0, kwcount=0, defs=0x0, 
    defcount=0, kwdefs=0x0, closure=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3433
#15 0x080f4c31 in PyEval_EvalCode (co=0xb7207b88, globals=0xb72e67a4, 
    locals=0xb72e67a4) at Python/ceval.c:771
#16 0x081365ca in run_mod (mod=0xa259258, 
    filename=0xb72ab840 "./WorldUnitsConvert.py", globals=0xb72e67a4, 
    locals=0xb72e67a4, flags=0xbfbceed8, arena=0xa21ddd0)
    at Python/pythonrun.c:1981
#17 0x081363ee in PyRun_FileExFlags (fp=0xa252c60, 
    filename=0xb72ab840 "./WorldUnitsConvert.py", start=257, 
    globals=0xb72e67a4, locals=0xb72e67a4, closeit=1, flags=0xbfbceed8)
    at Python/pythonrun.c:1937
#18 0x08134ad0 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags (fp=0xa252c60, 
    filename=0xb72ab840 "./WorldUnitsConvert.py", closeit=1, flags=0xbfbceed8)
    at Python/pythonrun.c:1447
#19 0x08133d5f in PyRun_AnyFileExFlags (fp=0xa252c60, 
    filename=0xb72ab840 "./WorldUnitsConvert.py", closeit=1, flags=0xbfbceed8)
    at Python/pythonrun.c:1169
#20 0x081569a7 in run_file (fp=0xa252c60, 
    filename=0xb7567028 L"./WorldUnitsConvert.py", p_cf=0xbfbceed8)
    at Modules/main.c:306
#21 0x081575ae in Py_Main (argc=2, argv=0xb7565028) at Modules/main.c:743
#22 0x0805c8f6 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbfbcf074) at ./Modules/python.c:58
(gdb) quit
```

Comment: Unfortunately the very nice automated process didn't work.  I got a error from report-bug complaining the apport module was not installed, installed pytyon-apport and although I can see the module installed -- it still doesn't work.  Finally found a launchpad page where you can report a bug against a package and turned it in there.

Comment: I'm glad you found a good way to report it. Assuming you included that stack trace and a description of what triggered the bug, it should be possible for the developers to investigate it and implement a solution. Since you've found the answer, I recommend [posting it as an answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). Alternatively it could be closed as a duplicate of [How do I submit a full bug report with crash dump and steps to reproduce?](http://askubuntu.com/q/150476) and you could add the answer there (or of [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121)).