# 'sudo lshw' yielding unexpected output

Tags: 14.04, chromebook

I'm running ChrUbuntu 14.04 LTS on my Asus M004U Chromebox, and I wanted to find out information about the disks connected.

I tried `sudo lshw`, but got `command not found`. After attempting to install it using `sudo apt-get install lshw`, executing `sudo lshw` gave me:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! That is unusual! This crash's probably a bug; so this may be closed as off-topic (see [the help](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)). I recommend [reporting this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). You can [make Apport collect/submit technical info](http://askubuntu.com/a/244982). Please [first read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). If you choose to report this as a bug, you can post the bug link here and/or please feel free to subscribe [me](https://launchpad.net/~degeneracypressure) (though I can't promise I'll be able to help).

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these commands:

sudo lshw -class disk -class storage

or

sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda