# Create bug report from "Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error"

Tags: bug-reporting, apport

I get this message very often:

[image: Sorry, Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error]

it happens 1-2 times daily, since ~1 year. The default is to send an error report "to help fix this problem".

It's clear that not all error reports can go to [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/) without flooding the platform. From [How can I track a bug that caused a crash and was reported via apport / whoopsie?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140379/how-can-i-track-a-bug-that-caused-a-crash-and-was-reported-via-apport-whoopsie), I learned that the errors go to https://errors.ubuntu.com/, but they don't seem to be more than a pixel in a chart.

My Question is: **How can I create a bug report in a similar way as manually calling `apport-bug`/`ubuntu-bug` would do for running processes?**, so that I can track its progress and add some more information (attachments, text) about it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/244982/158442?

Comment: @muru Yes, this perfectly solved the problem. Thx